# how to pass the dates to the x-axis in the base line high charts instead of the values

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

This the base line Highcharts which is having the values on the x-axis and percent on the y-axis,
please share how to pass the dates to the x-axis instead of the values so that, this is my highcharts code.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div> 

</body>   

      <script>

      $('#container').highcharts({
          title: {
              text: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
              x: -20 //center
          },
          tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
                //  console.log(this.point.extprop);
                  var s = 'The value is <b>' + this.x +
                      '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                  if (this.point.extprop) {
                      s += 'for <b>' + this.point.extprop + '</b>';
                  }
                  return s;
              }
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: '',
              x: -20
          },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Percent'
              },
              plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
              }]
          },
          legend: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              //align: 'right',
              //verticalAlign: 'middle',
              borderWidth: 0
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'RNA',
              data: [{
                  x: 0,
                  y: 99.43,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 1,
                  y: 99.40,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }, {
                  x: 2,
                  y: 99.24,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 3,
                  y: 99.40,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }, {
                  x: 4,
                  y: 99.21,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 5,
                  y: 98.45,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }, {
                  x: 6,
                  y: 98.41,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 7,
                  y: 99.18,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }, {
                  x: 8,
                  y: 99.36,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 9,
                  y: 99.31,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }, {
                  x: 10,
                  y: 99.38,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 11,
                  y: 99.20,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }, {
                  x: 12,
                  y: 99.38,
                  extprop: 'power issue'
              }, {
                  x: 13,
                  y: 99.32,
                  extprop: 'flood'
              }]
          }],
          credits: {
              enabled: false
          }
      });

</script>
</html>
```

This is the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/hj22wbe5/

i want to pass the dates to x-axis instead of the values..
like this 18-Jul-14', 19-Jul-14, 20-Jul-14....   so that the graph plot according to the dates and percent...

please help

thanks ...

Comment: You can use categories or datetime type of xAxis. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the dates and they are fixed, for example consider below your dates' array:

```
dates: ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14']
```

then you can use xAxis: categories to show these dates on xAxis like:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14'],
    labels:{rotation: 90, x:-20}
},
```

im giving further options such as labels' rotation of 90 degrees, its because there is not enough space for them to fit horizontally, they get mixed up that's why now they will be shown vertically like they should be.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/1/)**

Comment: HI @abdul jabbar ,  i have one more question how to pass the trend line in this graph ...if you dont get an idea .. please check my profile i asked question about trend line passing in the base line highcharts ... thanks

Comment: 'how to calculate the trend line' ?

Comment: what's the question? doesn't it contain the code for the trend line production in the fiddle?

Comment: the x-axis and y-axis values in the sourcedata, according to this sourcedata the trend line plot on the graph and here the fitdata function will pass the values to the regression.js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/2/ here is the fiddle containing the trendline of your chart with your values..

Comment: Thanks @abdul ....i have one more question without mouse over how to put static tooltip ..i mean the tool tip has to show when the graph is loaded ...without mouse over

Comment: regression.js is not included ...? without the regression.js the graph is plotting ..?

Comment: make sure you include all the libraries, <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> along with regression and jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/3/ this will show static tooltip for first point data[0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60865/discussion-between-abdul-jabbar-and-john).

Comment: how to remove the tooltip on the trend line when mouse over

Comment: and one more question why the animation effect is not working in ie10, ie8 ... like when the graph loads, the animation effect of baseline will pass on the graph

Answer (score 1):

Set your xAxis type to 'datetime'.

You can then either

- pass your dates as part of your data array
- use pointStart and pointInterval to handle the proper date alignment

Using categories for dates is both counterintuitive and loses all of the benefits of a datetime axis.

References:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

Comment: hi , why the animation effect is not working in ie10, ie8 ... like when the graph loads, the animation effect of baseline will pass on the graph

Comment: how to change the color of the point to red color when the point is lower on the graph ? ...thanks